# Do we have / what is our policy for discussing firmware?

Tags: discussion

[This question](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/q/16017/16811) about tweaking G-code to change Z-offset attracted [this answer](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/a/16018/16811).

I left a comment linking to the G-code list on the site for Marlin firmware as a further resource.

The author, a moderator, responded:

> It would be better to point people to the [RepRap G-code reference](https://reprap.org/wiki/G-code), this site is not firmware specific but targets more firmware flavors.

But that confused me. I don't see any meta question outlining a 3DPSE policy that it is not firmware specific.

I thought answers should be as relevant to the question as possible on the stack exchange network. The OP of the question flagged it for a Creality Ender 3, which uses Marlin, so why is it not better to refer to a Marlin site?

After all, RepRap, while it does use the same G-code as Marlin, is a specific firmware. If we do have a policy of always linking to neutral G-code references, wouldn't it be better to link to something like the [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/G-code) entry for G-code?

So I'm looking for clarification on site policy/best practices.

Answer (score 2):

The OP has a stock Ender 3 plate, but doesn't mention the firmware running on the printer. It could be stock, but it could be something different as well, the OP doesn't mention it. You are totally right to assume that this is Marlin, but it could be different (but not likely).

The stock firmware is Marlin of the Ender 3, which is probably on about 80-90 % of all printers. With "site" in the comment is meant the RepRap website that is linked, not the 3DP.SE site. Please note that the RepRap website is not firmware specific, you can find more firmware flavors, hence the reference to point to that reference. Maybe a comment on the question if the printer is running stock firmware would have made things more clear, I should have asked that, my bad. But the answer doesn't contain a firmware specific reference, it is in comments only. Comments are transient and are frequently deleted.

> I thought answers should be as relevant to the question as possible on the stack exchange network

True, I've asked the OP for the firmware running on the printer, then we know for sure. We could even reference to the [Marlin sources](https://github.com/MarlinFirmware/Marlin/blob/2.0.x/Marlin/src/gcode/motion/G0_G1.cpp) to show that the `G0` and `G1` are exactly the same.

Thanks for reminding that sometimes it is better to further question the OP in comments to make the problem more clear so that the answers can be written as relevant as possible. Sometimes it is easy to answer while it is better to make the question more clear.